# How to display d3js chart inside div of vertical tab content box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm currently trying to display a linegraph I created with `d3.js` inside the content box of a vertical tab menu. The d3 code for the graph itself would work on a "plain" page and even the logs inside the d3 code work when i put the code inside the tab content box but the graph just won't show. Other items inside the content box such as images or headings work just fine.

This is the html part of my code

```
  <h1 id="testheading"> Test </h1>
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openArg(event,'Overview')"> Übersicht </button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openArg(event,'JungAlt')"> Jung und Alt </button>
  </div>

  <div id="Overview" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div id="chart-area"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="JungAlt" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Jung und Alt</h3>
    <p>Kaufkraft ist sehr hoch</p>
  </div>
```

As expected, the content of the `csv` file which is used for the chart will be logged properly. Just the chart won't show inside the content box

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The d3.js script and the JavaScript code were initialised at the wrong place.